# How to pass values into not created function

Tags: javascript, function

I have a question how to pass value into function inside a `forEach` template string. As you can see in my code `forEach` loop is creating html card element with button inside. I only idea i have is to create onclick in html but i know this is **not acceptable**. Could you please help how to solve this problem. I mean how to pass this value without maiking onclick inside of html element.

thanks

```
let searchInput = document.getElementById('search');

class fetchData {

    constructor() {
        this.apiKey = ''
    }

    async getMovies(movie) {
        const movieRes = await fetch(`http://www.omdbapi.com/?apikey=${this.apiKey}&s=${movie}`)
        const moveData = await movieRes.json()
        return {
            moveData
        }
    }
}
const fetchMovie = new fetchData

searchInput.addEventListener('keyup', (e) => {
    let input = e.target.value;

    if (input !== '') {
        fetchMovie.getMovies(input)
            .then(res => {
                let data = res.moveData.Search

                if (!data) {
                    return false
                } else {
                    let output = ''
                    data.forEach(movie => {
                        let poster
                        if (movie.Poster === "N/A") {
                            poster = `https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/ac/No_image_available.svg`
                        } else {
                            poster = movie.Poster
                        }
                        output += `

                    <div class="card">
                    <img class="card-img-top" src="${poster}" alt="Card image cap">
                    <div class="card-body">
                      <h5 class="card-title text-left">${movie.Title}</h5>
                      <p class="card-text text-left">${movie.Year}</p>
                      <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="getID('${movie.imdb}')">Get details</a>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                    `
                    });
                    document.getElementById('container').innerHTML = output;
                }
            })
            .catch(err => console.log(err))
    }
    e.preventDefault();
})

function getID(id) {
    sessionStorage('movieID', id)

}
```

Comment: *create onclick in html but i know this is not acceptable* Why do you know that this is unacceptable? What exactly are you saying you want to do and why do you believe it is unacceptable?

Comment: What is the problem? any error? any problem??

Comment: i was said it is a bad practice. just it,

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to avoid using the HTML attribute `onclick` you can assign the event listener to the new elements, as they are generated in your code.  If you use JavaScript's ability to create elements (vs. inserting HTML as a string) you can capture the reference to a new element as you could with HTML elements that existed outside of JS.

```js
const data = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six'];
const target = document.getElementById('output');

data.forEach( d =>{
  let div = document.createElement('div');
  let btn = document.createElement('button');
  let txt = document.createTextNode( d );
  btn.addEventListener('click', function(){
    alert( d );
  });
  btn.appendChild( txt );
  div.appendChild( btn );
  target.appendChild( div );
});
```

```html
<div id="output"><div>
```

In my honest opinion, there is nothing wrong with using `onclick` on your HTML elements.  As long as your code (1) executes as expected, (2) is easy to read, and (3) can be maintained by others -- then the "how" you accomplish your goal is not super critical.

I believe the idea to depart from `onclick` is to keep priorities separate (structure in the HTML, logic in the JS, ...) but in your example you're generating your structure in the JS :) So, you already have your click logic in your JS code.

Comment: ok thanks, i was asking becasue it was said as a bad practice. but it make sense